# key_load_public: invalid format with scp or git clone on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, git, openssh

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10, when using `scp` or `git clone`, I get the following warning (the command itself doesn't fail): `key_load_public: invalid format`

How can I get rid of this warning?

Update:
This is the output of `scp -vvv`:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ... [...] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
key_load_public: invalid format
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9p1 Ubuntu-2
```

Comment: There should be more than only a `key_load_public: invalid format`

Comment: please, post the whole verbose log.

Comment: @Jakuje Added the verbose output to the question.

Comment: I meant rather verbose log from `scp`, such as `scp -vvv file remote:file` or so to see the context from ssh

Comment: @Jakuje Updated it again - is this sufficient?

Comment: Updated the output again (now from Ubuntu instead of OS X) but result is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check the file `/Users/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_rsa`. What is there? How did it get there?

It should be your private RSA key, isn't it? And is there something in `/Users/alexzeitler/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`? Is it valid public key?

If you don't use these keys, remove both of them and the message will disappear. If you are using them in different way, move them somewhere else. The same if they are in different format.

The public part is probably corrupted, so you can recreate it from private one using this command:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

###hostkeys possibility
The other possibility is that client is trying to read server public keys for `HostBasedAuthentication`. Don't you have it allowed in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` ?

It would be one of these files missing or corrupted:

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

Your `sshd` server is not complaining?

Comment: The public and private keys are valid when e.g. using them with git + GitHub

Comment: edited the answer. The server keys can be also the cause in some cases.

Comment: `HostBasedAuthentication no` in  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. None of the `.pub` files exists at `/etc/ssh/`. Also again copied the keys from another Ubuntu instance (14.04) that works fine and same error. On the other machine `/etc/ssh/` neither contains any of the `.pub` files from your answer.

Comment: Back to the first one. Openssh can basically create public key from private part. Can you try the same once more with the public part moved away? No other keys are never read and with each one tried, there is debug note and this is obviously related to the `rsa` one.

Comment: When removing the `.pub` key, I get this: `debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0` but no more `key_load_public: invalid format`

Comment: That one was there before. I believe the public  part is corrupted somehow. You can try to regenerate new public key from the private using `ssh-keygen -y ~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Comment: recreating the public key from the private fixed it - thanks for your help and patience! Please update the answer so I can mark it as answer.

Comment: Btw the command I used was: `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -y > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error `Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format` when I tried in a Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "$ssh_prv_key" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa &&     chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This led to errors like `identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1 invalid format` and `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty`. Do not use `echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" >> /root/.ssh/id_rsa` to pass the private key!

The right way would be to use

```
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The solution explained: my private key was wrongly formatted - instead of many lines, it was passed as a one-liner, and you might have any other format issue like a forgotten "-" at the start or end, or something wrong at the end of the lines, like a missing newline format or an additional letter at the end of a line.

See [Dockerfile: clone repo with passwordless private key. Errors: “authentication agent” or “read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty”](https://superuser.com/questions/1633085/dockerfile-clone-repo-with-passwordless-private-key-errors-authentication-ag) for more details, with the main idea from [Add private key to ssh-agent in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400527/11154841), which again had the idea from [Gitlab CI/Docker: ssh-add keeps asking for passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829291/nohup-causes-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty/66647740#66647740).